# Is it fine to roast someone?

Tags: halal-haram

Assalamu alaikum brother, I see on YouTube people criticising or roasting others work or art .
Is this fine ? Because to consider it as back biting they don't talk behind their backs . They openly criticise them . And roasting is common nowadays. Is it fine to watch those videos???

Answer (score 1):

Roasting is ridicule and insult. It is haram.

> O you who have believed, let not a people ridicule [another] people;
> perhaps they may be better than them; nor let women ridicule [other]
> women; perhaps they may be better than them. And do not insult one
> another and do not call each other by [offensive] nicknames. Wretched
> is the name of disobedience after [one's] faith. And whoever does not
> repent - then it is those who are the wrongdoers.

https://quran.com/49/11

Answer (score -2):

Salaam,
It is totally fine watching those videos because they are there to entertain. They are just jokes. Some celebs even like watching people roast them because its all just fun and not meant to be taken seriously in my opinion.
Hope that helps.
Michelle

Answer (score -2):

Waalaikumussalam,

Thats is all about personal, do you like being roasted ? If so, then that's Alright by you.

Some people don't like being roast, and some sensitive about it,

Prophet Muhammad Never roast Sahabat ever, why don't we just follow him right ?

We don't know people heart, and every word that we utter will be ASKED in the day of judgement,

people who got unjust/oppressed can CLAIM BACK in that day,

We don't want our Amal to get taken just because we say something bad right,

Wallahualam.